# Comparing number of lines in a CSV compared to number successfully processed into dataframe by Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

We are using Pandas to read a CSV into a dataframe:

```
 someDataframe = pandas.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=our_filepath_here,
        error_bad_lines=False,
        warn_bad_lines=True
    )
```

Since we are allowing bad lines to be skipped, we want to be able to track how many have been skipped and put it into a value so that we can metric off of it.

To do this, I was thinking of comparing how many rows we have in the dataframe vs the number of rows in the original file.

I think this does what I want:

```
someDataframe = pandas.read_csv(
   filepath_or_buffer=our_filepath_here,
   error_bad_lines=False,
   warn_bad_lines=True
)

initialRowCount = sum(1 for line in open('our_filepath_here'))
difference = initialRowCount - len(someDataframe.index))
```

But the hardware running this is super limited and I would rather not open the file and iterate through the whole thing just to get a row count when we're already going through the whole thing once via .read_csv. Does anyone know of a better way to get both the successfully processed count and the initial row count for the CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't tested this personally, I believe you can count the number of warnings generated by capturing them and checking the length of the returned list of captured warnings. Then add that to current shape of your dataframe:

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warning_list:
    someDataframe = pandas.read_csv(
       filepath_or_buffer=our_filepath_here,
       error_bad_lines=False,
       warn_bad_lines=True
    )

# May want to check if each warning object a pandas "bad line warning"
number_of_warned_lines = len(warning_list)

initialRowCount = len(someDataframe) + number_of_warned_lines
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings

---

Edit: took a little bit of toying around, but this seems to work with Pandas. Instead of depending on the warnings built-in, we'll just temporarily redirect `stderr`. Then we can count the number of times "Skipping Lines" occurs in that string and we'll end with the count of bad lines with this warning message!

```
import contextlib
import io

bad_data = io.StringIO("""
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
f,g,h,i,j,
l,m,n,o
p,q,r,s
7,8,9,10,11
""".lstrip())

new_stderr = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stderr(new_stderr):
    df = pd.read_csv(bad_data, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
    
n_warned_lines = new_stderr.getvalue().count("Skipping line")

print(n_warned_lines) # 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, pandas just outputs their "warnings" to stderr so it doesn't look like they'd be able to get recorded by this .catch_warnings (which would have been great!). So my original question still applies :( 

I tried running this code and got an empty warning list and ```Skipping line 7: expected 17 fields, saw 20\nSkipping line 11: expected 17 fields, saw 20``` just printed out in stderr

Comment: Just added another approach: redirecting stderr and counting the number of times the "Skipping line" substring occurs to get the number of those warnings generated. I tested this one and it worked with a small dummy data set.